# How do you travel to dungeons outside of your alliance?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

When I use the dungeon group finder, it gives me the option to find groups for dungeons that are outside of my alliance.

Last night the group finders assembled a group of us to go to City of Ash, but none of us had the location on our maps, and the area is outside of our alliance.

How are we supposed to get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the group dungeons that don't belong to your own faction, you'll first have to talk to the Undaunted and become one of them (this is optional, if you've got someone else "opening" the dungeons for you).

Talking to them will reveal the dungeon locations (read: map pins) for your current zone/tier.

Complete the group dungeon belonging to your current zone (i.e. your own faction) first. For example, if you start in the Daggerfall Covenant, the first group dungeon to be completed would be *Spindleclutch*. Once completed, the other two group dungeons of that tier will be open to you.

Once visible on your map and unlocked, you can just click the group dungeon icon to travel there (it's essentially a wayshrine).

Note that each and every faction got their own instances of those dungeons, i.e. you can't group with someone from another alliance to run these dungeons. The story and content are identical though.

Comment: So, since I am a Khajiit, would I talk to the Undaunted in Vulkhel Guard? Or are there level-appropriate NPCs? Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: If you're a Khajiit in the Aldmeri Dominion, talking to the Undaunted in Vulkhel Guard will unlock the *Banished Cells* as well as *Spindleclutch* and *Fungal Grotto*, but you'll have to complete *banished Cells* at least once to make the others valid travel targets. For the other tiers of dungeons, you'll have to find the Undaunted in the other taverns (typically one per zone).

Answer (score 0):

You can do all group dungeons that are open for your tier/level. If you try to walk out of the dungeon in another faction, you will be teleported back to your own faction area. :)

So just zoom out the map and zoom in on another alliance's area and click on the available dungeon markers to teleport there. :)

Source: http://forums.elderscrollsonline.com/discussion/125392/public-dungeons-in-other-alliance-zones